What are the norms of the generators of the standard Podleś sphere?
Fix a real number $0<q<1$. We consider the standard Podles sphere $A_q$ as the universal unit $C^*$-algebra generated by $a$ and $b$ with relations
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
&a=a^*,~ ab=q^2ba, ~ab^*=q^{-2}b^*a,\\
&bb^*=q^{-2}a(1-a), ~b^*b=a(1-q^2a).
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
See for example Section 3.1 Geometry of Quantum Spheres.
It seems to me that $A_q$ is only defined by the universal property. Although certain properties of $A_q$ can by obtained, I know very little about its elements. I even have the following basic question:

Can we compute the norms $\lVert a\rVert$ and $\lVert b\rVert$ in $A_q$?


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I’ve now provided a concrete description of $A_q$ and $a, b \in A_q$ in my answer, which should give you any information you may want on its elements, not just the norms of $a$ and $b$.

As it turns out, $A_q$ is just the unitization of the algebra of compact operators. $a$ is a diagonal compact operator, while $b$ is the product of a diagonal compact operator and the unilateral shift.

We have $\|a\| = 1$. For $b$, we have $\|b\| = \sqrt{1-q^2}$ if $q < \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$. If $q \geq \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$ is of the form $q = \sqrt[2m+2]{\frac{1}{2}}$ for some integer $m \geq 0$, then we have $\|b\| = \frac{1}{2q}$. Otherwise, we still have $\|b\| \leq \frac{1}{2q}$ whenever $q \geq \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$. (See the second and third parts of this answer for what exactly $\|b\|$ is in this case.)
We first show that $\|a\| \leq 1$. Observe that $a$ is self-adjoint and $a(1-a) = q^2bb^\ast$ is positive, so by functional calculus, $0 \leq a \leq 1$. Thus, $\|a\| \leq 1$. Now, $\|b\|^2 = \|b^\ast b\| = \|a(1-q^2a)\|$. Since $0 \leq a \leq 1$, by functional calulus,
$$0 \leq a(1-q^2a) \leq \begin{cases}\frac{1}{4q^2}, &\text{ if }\frac{1}{2} \leq q^2\text{, i.e., }q \geq \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\\ 1-q^2, &\text{ if } q < \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\end{cases}$$
Thus, $\|b\| \leq \begin{cases} \frac{1}{2q}, &\text{ if }q \geq \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}\\ \sqrt{1-q^2}, &\text{ if }q < \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} \end{cases}$. For the inequalities in the other direction, we exhibit some actual operators $A, B$ on a Hilbert space $H$ that satisfies the required relations. Let $H = \ell^2(\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0})$. Let $A$ be the diagonal operator defined by,
$$A(e_n) = q^{2n}e_n$$
And $B$ be defined by,
$$B(e_n) = q^n\sqrt{1-q^{2n+2}}e_{n+1}$$
We verify that $A$ and $B$ satisfy the conditions defining $a$ and $b$. Clearly, $A$ is self-adjoint. And,
$$AB(e_n) = q^n\sqrt{1-q^{2n+2}}A(e_{n+1}) = q^{3n+2}\sqrt{1-q^{2n+2}}e_{n+1}$$
Meanwhile,
$$q^2BA(e_n) = q^{2n+2}B(e_n) = q^{3n+2}\sqrt{1-q^{2n+2}}e_{n+1}$$
So $AB = q^2BA$. Taking adjoints immediately yields $AB^\ast = q^{-2}B^\ast A$. Moreover, we may verify that,
$$B^\ast(e_n) = \begin{cases} 0, &\text{ if }n = 0 \\ q^{n-1}\sqrt{1-q^{2n}}e_{n-1}, &\text{ if }n \geq 1\end{cases}$$
So,
$$BB^\ast(e_n) = \begin{cases} 0, &\text{ if }n = 0 \\ q^{n-1}\sqrt{1-q^{2n}}B(e_{n-1}) = q^{2(n-1)}(1-q^{2n})e_n, &\text{ if }n \geq 1\end{cases}$$
Note that when $n = 0$, we have $1-q^{2n} = 0$, so $BB^\ast(e_n) = q^{2(n-1)}(1-q^{2n})e_n$ is true for all $n$. Meanwhile,
$$q^{-2}A(1-A)(e_n) = q^{-2}q^{2n}(1-q^{2n})e_n = q^{2(n-1)}(1-q^{2n})e_n$$
So $BB^\ast = q^{-2}A(1-A)$. Finally,
$$B^\ast B(e_n) = q^n\sqrt{1-q^{2n+2}}B^\ast(e_{n+1}) = q^{2n}(1-q^{2n+2})e_n$$
Meanwhile,
$$A(1-q^2A)(e_n) = q^{2n}(1-q^{2n+2})e_n$$
So $B^\ast B = A(1-q^2A)$. Thus, there is a $\ast$-homomorphism $\pi: A_q \to \mathbb{B}(H)$ with $\pi(a) = A$ and $\pi(b) = B$. In particular, $\|A\| \leq \|a\|$, $\|B\| \leq \|b\|$. It is easy to see that $\|A\| = 1$, which shows $\|a\| = 1$. When $q < \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$, we have,
$$\|B\| = \sup_{n \geq 0} q^n\sqrt{1-q^{2n+2}} = \sqrt{1-q^2}$$
So $\|b\| = \sqrt{1-q^2}$ in this case. If $q = \sqrt[2m+2]{\frac{1}{2}}$ for some integer $m \geq 0$, then,
$$\|B\| = \sup_{n \geq 0} q^n\sqrt{1-q^{2n+2}} = q^m\sqrt{1-q^{2m+2}} = \frac{1}{2q}$$
So $\|b\| = \frac{1}{2q}$ in this case.

Edit: I've now found an argument that deals with the remaining cases, as follows.
Here is a proof that any representation of $A_q$ on a separable Hilbert space is a direct sum of copies of the representation in the first part of my answer (which, for clarity's sake, we shall call the standard representation) and possibly a zero part (i.e., a part on which $a, b$ both act as $0$. The identity operator still acts as the identity). Despite the representation not being assumed faithful, I’ll abuse the notations slightly and still just use $a$, $b$ and so on to denote the operators corresponding to these elements of $A_q$ under the given representation.
We first consider $\ker(a)$. On $\ker(a)$, $bb^\ast = q^{-2}a(1-a)$ and $b^\ast b = a(1-q^2a)$ both act as the zero operator, so $b$ and $b^\ast$ both act as the zero operator on $\ker(a)$ and $\ker(a)^\perp$ is invariant under both $b$ and $b^\ast$. This is the zero part of the representation. By cutting down by $p_{\ker(a)^\perp}$, we may now assume WLOG that $a$ is injective.
The spectrum of $a$ now consists of a discrete part and a diffuse part, and we correspondingly decompose our Hilbert space into the discrete part $H_d$ and the diffuse part $H_c$. We first consider $H_d$, which is spanned by eigenvectors of $a$. If $h$ is a unit eigenvector of $a$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then,
$$ab^\ast(h) = q^{-2}b^\ast a(h) = q^{-2}\lambda b^\ast(h)$$
So $b^\ast(h)$ is either zero, or an eigenvector of $a$ with eigenvalue $q^{-2}\lambda$. But $a \leq 1$, so all eigenvalues of $a$ are bounded above by $1$, i.e., if $\lambda > q^2$, we must have $b^\ast(h) = 0$. However,
$$0 = \|b^\ast(h)\|^2 = \langle h, bb^\ast h\rangle = \langle h, q^{-2}a(1-a)h\rangle = q^{-2}\lambda(1-\lambda)$$
As $0 \leq a \leq 1$ and $a$ is assumed injective, this implies $\lambda = 1$. Thus, the only eigenvalue of $a$ that is larger than $q^2$ is $1$. This also shows that, when $\lambda \neq 1$, $b^\ast(h)$ is nonzero, so for any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $a$ that is not $1$, we have $q^{-2}\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue.
On the other hand, again suppose $h$ is a unit eigenvector of $a$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then,
$$ab(h) = q^2ba(h) = q^2\lambda b(h)$$
And,
$$\|b(h)\|^2 = \langle h, b^\ast bh\rangle = \langle h, a(1-q^2a)h\rangle = \lambda(1-q^2\lambda) \neq 0$$
As $\lambda > 0$ and $q^2\lambda \leq q^2 < 1$. Hence, $b(h)$ is an eigenvector of $a$ with eigenvalue $q^2\lambda$, so for any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $a$, $q^2\lambda$ is an eigenvalue as well.
Combining the above, we see that, if $a$ admits any eigenvalue, the set of eigenvalues must be exactly,
$$\sigma_e(a) = \{1, q^2, q^4, \cdots\}$$
We now show that eigenspaces of different eigenvalues are actually isomorphic to each other. Indeed, for $n \geq 0$, the map,
$$\pi_{0n}: 1_{\{1\}}(a) \to 1_{\{q^{2n}\}}(a), \pi(h) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} q^{2i}(1-q^{2i+2})}}b^n(h)$$
is a well-defined isometry. (This easily follows from the fact that whenever $h$ is a unit eigenvector of $a$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $\|b(h)\|^2 = \lambda(1-q^2\lambda)$ and $b(h)$ is an eigenvector of $a$ with eigenvalue $q^2\lambda$, as we have seen before.) Its conjugate is,
$$\pi_{0n}^\ast: 1_{\{q^{2n}\}}(a) \to 1_{\{1\}}(a), \pi^\ast(h) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\prod_{i=1}^n q^{2i-2}(1-q^{2i})}}(b^\ast)^n(h)$$
We note that $\pi_{0n}^\ast$ is also an isometry. (This follows from the fact that whenever $h$ is a unit eigenvector of $a$ with eigenvalue $\lambda \neq 1$, then $\|b^\ast(h)\|^2 = q^{-2}\lambda(1-\lambda)$ and $b^\ast(h)$ is an eigenvector of $a$ with eigenvalue $q^{-2}\lambda$, as we have seen before.) But this means $\pi_{0n}$ is a unitary, so we may identify all eigenspaces with $1_{\{1\}}(a)$. Thus,
$$H_d = \ell^2(\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}) \otimes 1_{\{1\}}(a)$$
And both $a$ and $b$ only act on the first tensor component, with $a$ acting as the diagonal operator $\text{diag}(1, q^2, q^4, \cdots)$ while,
$$\begin{split}
b(e_n \otimes h) &= b\pi_{0n}\pi_{0n}^\ast(e_n \otimes h)\\
&= \frac{\sqrt{\prod_{i=0}^n q^{2i}(1-q^{2i+2})}}{\sqrt{\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} q^{2i}(1-q^{2i+2})}}\pi_{0(n+1)}\pi_{0n}^\ast(e_n \otimes h)\\
&= (q^n\sqrt{1-q^{2n+2}}e_{n+1}) \otimes h
\end{split}$$
So $H_d$ is just the direct sum of $\dim(1_{\{1\}}(a))$ copies of the standard representation.
Note that this entire argument has also shown that $H_d$ is a reducing subspace of $A_q$, so $H_c = H_d^\perp$ is reducing as well, and we shall now restrict to $H_c$. Our claim is that, in fact, $H_c = 0$. To prove this, assume to the contrary that $H_c \neq 0$. We first note that, by tensoring with $\ell^2$ and applying the spectral theorem (recall that $0 \leq a \leq 1$), we may assume $H_c = L^2([0, 1], \mu) \otimes \ell^2$ for some atomless probability measure $\mu$ on $[0, 1]$, where $a$ acts only on the first tensor component as multiplication by $x$. Fix $n > 0$ and $f \in H_c$ of unit length. Then for each $1 \leq i \leq n$, let $f_i = f|_{[\frac{i-1}{n}, \frac{i}{n}]}$. As $\mu$ is atomless, $f = \sum_{i=1}^n f_i$. Moreover, $1 = \|f\|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \|f_i\|^2$. Also observe that $\|a(f_i) - \frac{i}{n}f_i\| \leq \frac{1}{n}\|f_i\|$, so, if we let $g_i = b(f_i)$,
$$a(g_i) = ab(f_i) = q^2ba(f_i) = q^2\frac{i}{n}b(f_i) + q^2b(a(f_i) - \frac{i}{n}f_i) = q^2\frac{i}{n}g_i + q^2b(a(f_i) - \frac{i}{n}f_i)$$
So as $\|b\| \leq 1$, we have $\|(a - q^2\frac{i}{n})g_i\| \leq q^2\frac{1}{n}\|f_i\|$. But then,
$$q^2\frac{1}{n}\|f_i\| \geq \|1_{[\frac{q^2+1}{2}, 1]}(a - q^2\frac{i}{n})g_i\| \geq \frac{1-q^2}{2}\|1_{[\frac{q^2+1}{2}, 1]}b(f_i)\|$$
So $\|1_{[\frac{q^2+1}{2}, 1]}b(f_i)\| \leq \frac{2q^2}{n(1-q^2)}\|f_i\|$. Thus,
$$\begin{split}
\|b(f) - 1_{[0, \frac{q^2+1}{2}]}b(f)\| &= \|\sum_{i=1}^n 1_{[\frac{q^2+1}{2}, 1]}b(f_i)\|\\
&\leq \frac{2q^2}{n(1-q^2)}\sum_{i=1}^n \|f_i\|\\
&\leq \frac{2q^2}{n(1-q^2)}\sqrt{n}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n \|f_i\|^2}\\
&= \frac{2q^2}{n^{\frac{1}{2}}(1-q^2)}\\
&\to 0, \text{ as }n \to \infty
\end{split}$$
Hence, $b(f) = 1_{[0, \frac{q^2+1}{2}]}b(f)$. In particular, $b(f) \perp L^2([\frac{q^2+1}{2}, 1], \mu) \otimes \ell^2$ for all $f$. Thus, $b^\ast(L^2([\frac{q^2+1}{2}, 1], \mu) \otimes \ell^2) = 0$. But for $h \in L^2([\frac{q^2+1}{2}, 1], \mu) \otimes \ell^2$,
$$\|b^\ast(h)\|^2 = \langle h, bb^\ast(h)\rangle = q^{-2}\langle h, a(1-a)h\rangle$$
which can only be zero if $h$ is supported on $\{1\}$ - which, as $\mu$ is atomless, has measure zero. Whence, we must have $L^2([\frac{q^2+1}{2}, 1], \mu) = 0$, i.e., $\|a\| \leq \frac{q^2+1}{2}$.
At this point, one may repeat the argument above once more. This time, instead of dividing the interval $[0, 1]$ into $n$ subintervals, we divide $[0, \frac{q^2+1}{2}]$. Then the same argument shows $\|a\| \leq (\frac{q^2+1}{2})^2$. By repeatedly applying the argument, we then have $\|a\| \leq (\frac{q^2+1}{2})^m$ for all $m \geq 1$, which means $a = 0$ on $H_c$. As $a$ is assumed injective, this must mean $H_c = 0$. Thus, $H = H_d$ is a direct sum of copies of standard representations.
Remark: This also provides a concrete description of $A_q$, namely, as $A_q$ is separable, it admits a faithful representation on a separable Hilbert space, so $A_q = C^\ast(A \oplus 0, B \oplus 0, 1)$ for $A, B$ in the standard representation. In fact, as $A, B$ are compact, picking out the constant term is a character on $C^\ast(A, B, 1)$, so $A_q = C^\ast(A, B, 1)$ is also true. Also note that this means the standard representation is faithful. It is easy to see that the standard representation is irreducible, as $W^\ast(A, B, 1) = \mathbb{B}(H)$, so $A_q$ is primitive.
Edit: I realized that the argument never assumes the representation is faithful, so any representation on a separable Hilbert space is a direct sum of copies of the standard representation - which is faithful and irreducible, and a zero part (again, this means $a, b$ both act as $0$, but the identity still acts as the identity). So there are exactly two proper closed ideals of $A_q$, namely the zero ideal, which is primitive, and the ideal generated by $a$ and $b$, which is maximal - in fact, $A_q/\langle a, b \rangle = \mathbb{C}$. Actually, one easily verifies that $C^\ast(A, B)$ in the standard representation is just $\mathbb{K}(\ell^2)$, so $A_q$, for any $0 < q < 1$, is simply $\mathbb{K}(\ell^2) \oplus \mathbb{C}$ (the unitization of the algebra of compact operators). In particular, they are all isomorphic to each other.

As $A_q$ is separable, by the argument in the previous part, one would have the norm of $b$ is just the norm of $B$ in the standard representation, i.e., whenever $q \geq \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$,
$$\|b\| = q^{n_q}\sqrt{1-q^{2n_q+2}}, \text{ where }n_q = \text{argmin}_{n \geq 0} |q^{2n+2} - \frac{1}{2}|$$
which is distinct from $\frac{1}{2q}$ unless $q = \sqrt[2m+2]{\frac{1}{2}}$ for some integer $m \geq 0$.

Let me also mention that the norms are continuous in the limits $q \to 0$ and $q \to 1$. When $q = 1$, the relations define an abelian $C^\ast$-algebra with self-adjoint $a$ and an element $b$ s.t. $|b|^2 = a(1-a)$. It is not hard to check that this is simply the algebra of continuous functions on the unit sphere, with $a = \frac{1+z}{2}$ and $b = \frac{x+iy}{2}$ where $(x,y,z)$ are Cartesian coordinate functions (for a detailed proof of this fact, see my answer here). Thus, we have $\|a\| = 1$ and $\|b\| = \frac{1}{2}$. In $A_q$, when $q \geq \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$, recall that we have,
$$\|b\| = q^{n_q}\sqrt{1-q^{2n_q+2}}, \text{ where }n_q = \text{argmin}_{n \geq 0} |q^{2n+2} - \frac{1}{2}|$$
So $\|b\| \to \frac{1}{2}$ as $q \to 1$, consistent with the case where $q = 1$. For $q = 0$, we need to move $q^{-2}$ to the other sides of the equations in some relations for this to make sense, but we would end up with,
$$a = a^\ast, ab = b^\ast a = 0, a(1-a) = 0, b^\ast b = a$$
Thus, $a$ defines a self-adjoint projection and $b$ is a partial isometry whose initial space is $a$ and whose final space is orthogonal to $a$. (The algebra is just $M_2(\mathbb{C}) \oplus \mathbb{C}$, with $a = e_{11} \oplus 0$ and $b = e_{21} \oplus 0$.) Hence, we easily have $\|a\| = \|b\| = 1$ in this case. On the other hand, in $A_q$ when $q < \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$, we have $\|b\| = \sqrt{1-q^2}$, so indeed $\|b\| \to 1$ as $q \to 0$, consistent with the case where $q = 0$.

+1 for this  interesting answer.  honestly I am not familiar with  "universal algebra generated by  elements and  relations"  but I am curious  since 1 decade. For example  what  would we  lose or gain if  we add extra relation $[a,b]=-log(q)$ in this  or in any other universal algebra? because this condition consist with any commutative algebra in a  deformation of  $A_q$  with q close to 1

@AliTaghavi The relation is not satisfiable, since for any bounded $a, b$, $[a,b]$ cannot be a nonzero scalar.

yes I was  mistaken  that was  an ewxercise  in rudin functional  analysis. i am sorry.  But  by the above  comment  I was  actually thinking to the  maximality and  optimality of the set of  relations.   That was a random relation that I pointed out to(which was wrong. Ok replace it with another one say $-log(q)ab$. BTW the optimality requirement implies that we exclude the third relation in OP  question. do you agree?

To OP: The proof is now complete, with the remaining cases resolved and a concrete description of $A_q$ provided as a side product.

@AliTaghavi I'm not sure what your point is. The third condition is certainly redundant, but including it makes the relations more symmetric and aesthetically pleasing, at least to me. Whether it is optimal or not, I honestly couldn't care less.

@AliTaghavi You are certainly free to add more relations, you just get a quotient of $A_q$, that's all. That's not what the OP asked, nor do I find any reason why adding more (completely random, it seems) relations is interesting.

@AliTaghavi I just realized, funnily enough, that my proof implies $A_q$ are all isomorphic to $\mathbb{K}(\ell^2) \oplus \mathbb{C}$, the unitization of the algebra of compact operators, for any $0 < q < 1$. So I suppose that answers your previous question on whether these algebras are isomorphic, in the positive.
